# How to display 'Tooltip' for a Group (textbox + images) Assigned to Macro?

Tags: vba, tooltip, excel-2007

**Context:**

I have several groups that I've made in Excel 2007 that each consist of a textbox and image(s) and are each assigned to a macro.

What I would like is upon a mouseover/hover of the group, it displays a 'tooltip' that contains more detailed info about what the assigned macro does. I've come across what looks to be a solution here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=15084 However, I don't know how to figure out the assigned name to an image so I can use the name in the code, and I'm not sure how to incorporate it to use a Group object instead, or if it's even possible to do with groups.

**Question:**

As per title, how do I display a tooltip/infotip for a group (textbox + images) assigned to a macro?

**EDIT: I've enclosed a copy of the code found in the link so people don't have to go page hopping:**

Code that goes in a general, public module:

```
Option Explicit 

Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" ( _ 
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long 

Declare Function GetSysColor Lib "user32" ( _ 
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long 


Public Function CreateToolTipLabel(objHostOLE As Object, _ 
    sTTLText As String) As Boolean 
    Dim objToolTipLbl As OLEObject 
    Dim objOLE As OLEObject 

    Const SM_CXSCREEN = 0 
    Const COLOR_INFOTEXT = 23 
    Const COLOR_INFOBK = 24 
    Const COLOR_WINDOWFRAME = 6 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'just while label is created and formatted

    For Each objOLE In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects 
        If objOLE.Name = "TTL" Then objOLE.Delete 'only one can exist at a time
    Next objOLE 

     'create a label control...
    Set objToolTipLbl = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1") 

     '...and format it to look as a ToolTipWindow
    With objToolTipLbl 
        .Top = objHostOLE.Top + objHostOLE.Height - 10 
        .Left = objHostOLE.Left + objHostOLE.Width - 10 
        .Object.Caption = sTTLText 
        .Object.Font.Size = 8 
        .Object.BackColor = GetSysColor(COLOR_INFOBK) 
        .Object.BackStyle = 1 
        .Object.BorderColor = GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWFRAME) 
        .Object.BorderStyle = 1 
        .Object.ForeColor = GetSysColor(COLOR_INFOTEXT) 
        .Object.TextAlign = 1 
        .Object.AutoSize = False 
        .Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) 
        .Object.AutoSize = True 
        .Width = .Width + 2 
        .Height = .Height + 2 
        .Name = "TTL" 
    End With 
    DoEvents 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

     'delete the tooltip window after 5 secs
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "DeleteToolTipLabels" 

End Function 

Public Sub DeleteToolTipLabels() 
    Dim objToolTipLbl As OLEObject 
    For Each objToolTipLbl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects 
        If objToolTipLbl.Name = "TTL" Then objToolTipLbl.Delete 
    Next objToolTipLbl 
End Sub
```

Code that goes in the sheet (right click sheet tab>code)

```
Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, _ 
    ByVal Shift As Integer, _ 
    ByVal X As Single, _ 
    ByVal Y As Single) 
    Dim objTTL As OLEObject 
    Dim fTTL As Boolean 

    For Each objTTL In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects 
        fTTL = objTTL.Name = "TTL" 
    Next objTTL 

    If Not fTTL Then 
        CreateToolTipLabel Image1, "ToolTip Label" 
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: The assigned name of an image can be obtained from the formula bar, or you could loop over the shapes in the worksheet, and use `Debug.Print shape.Name` to figure it out. See if you can get it to work for a single image, and then we can try and get it to work for Grouped objects.

Comment: Ah OK. I see now in the formula bar I get things like "Picture 13" or "Group 37". I created a command button like people did in the linked page, but w/o an assigned macro and changed the name through the formula bar to 'TestButton' and then changed Image1 to TestButton in both places in the second sub, but nothing happened when mousing over. I tried reopening the sheet but no change either.

Comment: +1 for a good question. Unfortunately I don't have time to work on this right now. Good luck!